# Socialengine 4 - Set module title using PHP

Tags: php, module, socialengine

I am writing a small module for Socialengine 4 and can't find a possibility to
set the page title ( tag) withing the module using php.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Zend framework's [HeadTitle Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headtitle).